# Filter elements from nested lists

Tags: list, haskell, filter

I am having a hard time with understanding the logic behind functional programming. So, this should be something quite easy but not working for me. 
What i am trying to do is: 
A function with a parameter list, and a list is something like this: `[[1,2,3], [5,7,8,12,34], [2,4,6,8]]`
and first i should delete the values less than 6 and then delete all the lists with less than 2 elements. My code is like this:

```
f11 :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
f11 xs = ( filter (\s -> if a <= 6 a then True else False )) (map (filter (\x -> length x <= 2)) xs)
```

Comment: Minor style comment: you can avoid the antipattern `if condition then True else False`, it can be simplified to `condition`. E.g., one can write `filter (\x -> x>=6) [1..10]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the `do` notation, thanks to lists' instance of `Monad`.

```
f11 xss = do
    xs <- xss
    let ys = [x | x <- xs, x >= 6]
    guard (length ys <= 2)
    return ys
```

`do` notation for *lists* basically denotes a `foreach` loop. We extract each element `xs` from `xss`, then feed it through a list comprehension to filter out the elements less than 6, naming the result `ys`. Then `guard` filters out `ys` longer than 2.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting it the other way around, check this:

```
f11 :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
f11  =  (filter \x-> length x < 2) . (map (filter \x -> x > 6))
```

Comment: I think this looks better with point-free predicates too, but I suppose some might disagree: `f11 = filter ((< 2) . length) . map (filter (>= 6))`.

Comment: @amalloy love that. Even better

Comment: Thanks. I just have to check what those "dots" do =)

Comment: @Pelin, the dots mean fucntion composition its like adding 2 function behaviour into one.

Comment: Great! Thank you for the explanation @Daniel Sanchez

Comment: @Pelin just for completeness, `((< 2) . length)  xs` == `(< 2) (length xs)` == `length xs < 2`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of taste, but, for readability, you might want to use intermediates:

```
f11 :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
f11 xs = 
    let 
        less6Cleared = map (filter (\x -> x >= 6)) xs
    in  
        filter (\x -> length(x) >= 2) less6Cleared
```

This says that `less6Cleared` is the list of lists whose all elements have been cleared of less than 6. You now apply a filter to `less6Cleared`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go crazy with point free style and partial function application...

```
f11 :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
f11 = (filter $ (>= 2) . length) . (map $ filter (>= 6))
```

... but it might not be clearer, especially to those not used to it.

Also I took your requirements of "less than" to be strict, so values of 6 are not deleted, and list of lengths of 2 are not deleted.